# Invalid application ID error after adding Admob

Tags: android, admob

I've implemented Admob in my android app and 'm recieving an error:

I've checked my app_id and its correct and i followed the instruction from:
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#update_your_androidmanifestxml

also tried adding Admob activity but the same error raised

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.*****.*******, PID: 2036
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

                  ******************************************************************************
                  * Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here: ***** *
                  * find your app ID.                                                          *
                  ******************************************************************************


                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4793)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4385)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4325)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

                  ******************************************************************************
                  * Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here: ***** to *
                  * find your app ID.                                                          *
                  ******************************************************************************


                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzze.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4790)
                        ... 12 more
```

Thanks for help.

## Update

Now its working, just replaced app_id with testing id

Comment: show your manifest file

Comment: Now its working, just replaced app_id with testing id